# Finding files with specific name and making output like txt

Tags: command-line, files

I used this command:

```
ls *tagme*
```

to make a list of file with partial word, but i ended up with allot more than terminal can show me.

And

```
ls *tagme* -print
```

but i don't know where and what printed.

So I need a command or script that can find and list, all files with their filename, in text(or other) document.

Comment: just use `ls *tagme* >out.txt` to save the output to a file named `out.txt` ..also `ls` does not have a `-print` option..

Comment: All files with a certain name or part of it, like *tagme*. But what i need is comm-line that can find files and make output list of those files.

Comment: Does not `ls` do that already? if not could you clarify what do you mean by `output list` ?

Comment: Sorry.  `ls *tagme* >out.txt` where does it create txt file, the same directory as files or elsewhere? Can txt file be created in specific location?

Comment: `out.txt` is created in the same directory in which you have done `ls`..it can be saved in a different directory too, just use the path to the directory e.g. `ls *tagme* >/where/to/save/out.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To output list to file use `>` operator for redirection;

```
ls *tagme* > outputFile.txt`
```

To view page list in terminal, use any of the paging commands , like `more`,`less` , `pg`

```
ls | less
```

Another paging method is to use `nano` with `--view` flag and bash's process redirection,

```
nano --view <(ls)
```